# How to use multiple firewalls in symfony 2.8 for same pattern?

Tags: symfony, oauth, hmac, api-key, symfony-security

I have a symfony 2.8 application that will be used as a REST API back end

I would like to add security to all end points matching ^/api
I would like to be able to use 3 different authentication method for ^/api

I am using uma/psr7-hmac-bundle, friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle, APIKey authentication.

I defined 3 different firewalls and everything works for each firewalls if I remove the other two.

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        oauth_token:
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
            security: false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/auth
            security: false

        api_key:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: api_key_authenticator
            provider: api_key_user_provider

        oauth_api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true 
            fos_oauth: true
            provider: oauth_user

        hmac_api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true  
            hmac: 
                apikey_header: 'X-Custom-Header-Key'
            provider: hmac_user
```

How can I use all 3 firewalls together (chain them)? (hmac_api, oauth_api, api_key)

I looked into Guards but I am not sure how to define/implement Authenticators for HMAC and oAuth.

I looked into firewall context but because it is stateless it won't work.

Basically how can I chain multiple firewalls for same pattern? or how can I define one firewall with 3 different authenticators with considering that I am using third part bundles like  friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle, uma/psr7-hmac-bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
guard:
    authenticators:
```

for chaining authenticators for your firewall
That's what I have in my app

```
api:
            pattern:   ^/api         
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - bor.api_bundle.session_authenticator
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                    - sergei_k_security.token_authenticator
                entry_point: lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html

Comment: How would you define authenticators for uma/psr7-hmac-bundle, friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle?